# Writing functions as powerseries and determining their radius of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm stuck on the question below, and dont know how to solve it. Would someone like to help me?

- Develop the following functions as power series and determine the radius of convergence: $\frac{1}{x-2}$

I've tried writing it as a geometric sum by following manipulations $\frac{1}{x-2}$ = $-\frac{1}{2}$$\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}$

$-\frac{1}{2}$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^k$ where $r=\frac{x}{2}$

I don't know if im doing anything right here, just trying different things to see if i get a answer thats close to the right answer.

Comment: You are on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Your manipulations so far are very good, but you have to be very careful. For example you are using the identity
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$  which is not true for all values of $x$, in fact it is only true for $-1<x<1$ (the right hand side is not defined outside of this interval).

Now you plug in $r=\frac{x}{2}$ to deduce that
$$-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}} =-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-r}= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^{n+1}}$$ but again this is not true for all $x$! As we said before, the second equality only holds when $-1<r<1$ which gives $-1<\frac{x}{2}<1$ which gives $-2<x<2$.

In this interval the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^{n+1}}$ converges to $\frac{1}{x-2} = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}$, we need to see if it converges outside of this interval. If we take $x=2$, we get an infinite sum of $\frac{1}{2}$, I mean $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^{n+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2}$, this clearly diverges.
If $x=-2$, we get the infinite sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{2}$ which also diverges (Why? hint: what is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(-1)^n\cdot \frac{1}{2}?$).

Based on this analysis, the radius of converges is $2$.